# Select Data from Group B with the missing Values from Group A

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I need to Group (or otherwise select) data from a database, here a simplified Model of that Database:

```
user: { id: int, name: varchar } 
scenario: { id: int, displayname: varchar, userId: int}
costgroup: { id: int, displayname: varchar }
costgroupvalue: { id: int, scenarioId: int, value: float, year: year, costgroupId: int}
```

There is one *Scenario* (Id: 1) with *CostGroupValues* ranging from 2012 to 2018 and one *Scenario* (Id: 2) with *CostGroupValues* ranging from 2016 to 2018.

What I need is: the *CostGroupValues* for one *Scenario* (Id: 2) but with the missing *CostGroupValues* from 2012 to 2015 from the other *Scenario* (Id: 1).

Here is an example of a query I already did:

```
SELECT costgroupvalue.*
FROM costgroup
JOIN costgroupvalue ON costgroup.id = costgroupvalue.costgroupid
JOIN scenario ON scenario.id = costgroupvalue.scenarioid
And scenario.userid = '666'
Group by costgroupvalue.id;
```

I marked the data I don't need from the above query result in yellow

[image: picture].

Comment: if you want "missing" values on one side of the query, you have to switch to using a `left` or `right` join, as appropirate. you're doing `inner` joins, which require that matching records be available on BOTH sides of the join.

Comment: if with "missing"-values you mean null-values, than no i don't whant these. I need the Rows with scenarioId 2 (that are only there from 2016 to 2018) with the Rows that have scenarioId 1 from the range of 2012 until there are Rows with Data and scenarioId 2 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution on my own:**

```
SELECT costgroupvalue.*
FROM costgroup
JOIN costgroupvalue ON costgroup.id = costgroupvalue.costgroupid
JOIN scenario ON scenario.id = costgroupvalue.scenarioid
AND scenario.userid = '14'
WHERE (scenario.id = 2 AND  costgroupvalue.year between '2016' AND '2018')
Or (scenario.id = 1 AND  costgroupvalue.year between '2012' AND '2015')
Group by costgroupvalue.id
Order by costgroupvalue.costgroupid, costgroupvalue.scenarioid, costgroupvalue.year
```

This Query gives me the Rows i need: ScenarioId = 1 from 2012 to 2015 and ScenarioId = 2 from 2016 to 2018.